# Is there a function for picking the max value in a pytorch tensor which follows a requirenment

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am programming an othello bot in python using reinforcment learning and pytorch. In the program, I scan the board for legal moves. The AI should choose the move with the highest probability of beeing good, and that is legal according to the previose calculation. Here I need a function that works something like this:

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
b = torch.tensor([True, True, False, True, False], dtype=bool)
print(torch.somefunction(a,b))
```

The output should be the id of the max value in a, in this case 3. Does this function exist? And if not, are there any other whay of doing this?

Comment: I've never played Othello. Though I think an easier approach would be to generate a set of `[0, 1]` masks over the board to zero out illegal moves. Then simply perform an `argmax` to get the index of the best move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is at least one non-negative value in your tensor, you multiply it by the mask itself to remove excluded values in the sorting:

```
>>> torch.argmax(a*b)
tensor(3)
```

If that's not the case, you can still get away with it, using [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html) by replacing the excluded values with some value that will get ignored by the argmax (*e.g.* `a.min()`):

```
>>> torch.where(b, a, a.min()).argmax()
tensor(3)
```